# Add custom scopes into JWT refresh token - AWS Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, jwt, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I have a question related to AWS Cognito custom scopes. I followed an [AWS article](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cognito-custom-scopes-api-gateway/) and enabled **allowed custom scopes** as mentioned in the screenshot. My problem is when I decode the accesstoken by [jwt site](https://jwt.io/), custom scopes are not included in the **scope** of the access token. Bellow I have attached a sample payload of a decorded access token for your reference. Is it possible to help me to add **custom scopes** to the **access token** generated by AWS Cognito?

[image]

```
"sub": "###",
  "event_id": "###",
  "token_use": "access",
  "scope": "aws.cognito.signin.user.admin",
  "auth_time": 1647489023,
  "iss": "https://cognito-idp.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/ap-southeast-2_###",
  "exp": 1647492623,
  "iat": 1647489023,
  "jti": "###",
  "client_id": "###",
  "username": "test-user"
}
```

**Update**:

I am acccessing Cognito via ASP.Net SDK. I sent username and password of the user to Cognito and received tokens.

Comment: In order to get the access token, how do you authenticate?

Comment: Asking because I believe I faced this issue but forgot which component is the problem. For example, seems this is a known issue with [amazon-cognito-identity-js](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/3732).

Comment: I am accessing the cognito via API endpoint (developed on .Net SDK) and send my username and password. Then they respond with ID, access and refresh tokens.